# When running the JNPL application ASDM, Loading freezes at 17 %. What may be the problem

Tags: java, jnlp, ubuntu-20.04

I have been trying to run ciscoASDM. After I run the command `javaws startup.jnlp` and app opens. After login, it goes freeze at 17%. What may be the problem?

I have java

```
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.16.0-openjdk-amd64      1611       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.16.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

```
$ javaws startup.jnlp 

selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Unable to use Firefox's proxy settings. Using "DIRECT" as proxy type.
selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Unable to use Firefox's proxy settings. Using "DIRECT" as proxy type.
Codebase matches codebase manifest attribute, and application is signed. Continuing. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/no_redeploy.html for details.
Starting application [com.cisco.launcher.Launcher] ...
asdm.runStartupWizard = true
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.trace.Trace
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1640)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.cisco.launcher.i.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.i.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.i.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:576)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:945)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this Github [issue](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/IcedTea-Web/issues/741), Cisco ASDM does not work with OpenJDK 8 because `deploy.jar` file is missing.